# react component not render new data from redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using react and redux, i want to update my counter value in react view, i am able to console latest state of my redux store but it is not reflect in my react view.

```
const counter = (state = 0, action) => {
  console.log(action);
  if(action.type == "INCREMENT")
    return state + 1;
  if(action.type == "DECREMENT")
    return state - 1;
  else 
    return state; // return same state if action not identified  
}

const {createStore} = Redux;

const store = createStore(counter);

class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <div>{this.props.state.getState()}</div>
      <button onClick={this.props.onIncrement} >INC</button>
      <button onClick={this.props.onDecrement} >DEC</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Counter 
    state={store} 
    onIncrement={
      () => store.dispatch({ type : "INCREMENT" })
    }
    onDecrement={
      () => store.dispatch({ type : "DECREMENT" })
    }
  />,
  document.querySelector('#counter'));
}

store.subscribe(function() {
  console.log(store.getState())
});

render();
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/cicejul/50/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: How your coupling your react component to redux state? You cannot directly access the redux state as props in the react component.

Comment: Use react-redux to bind to your react app http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React doesn't automatically re-render the view every time some Javascript data changes, even if your view is bound to that data.

A React component only re-renders in a few cases:

1. You call `this.setState({ ... })` inside the component
2. A parent React component is re-rendered

There are a few other ways to force a re-render, but they are not recommended because they are much slower and will make your app sluggish.

To correct your sample, do your data binding for actual data on the `state` object, rather than `props`. This way React knows to re-render just your component when the counter changes. This might not be very important in a small sample, but this is very important when you want to reuse your component or embed it in a larger page.

Then subscribe to your store, and in the callback invoke `setState` with any changes. That way React can decide when your re-render should actually happen.

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {counter: 0}; // Setup initial state
    this.storeUpdated = this.storeUpdated.bind(this);
    props.store.subscribe(this.storeUpdated); // Subscribe to changes in the store
  }

  storeUpdated() {
    this.setState( // This triggers a re-render
      {counter: this.props.store.getState()});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <div>{this.state.counter}</div>
      <button onClick={this.props.onIncrement} >INC</button>
      <button onClick={this.props.onDecrement} >DEC</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

After you've played with this for a while and gotten familiar with how Redux and React work, I suggest you check out this library:

- Get the library here: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux
- See http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html for a tutorial on this library

This handles the bridge between React and Redux in a much more clean way than you can achieve by manually doing all the bindings yourself.